How can I transfer input flowfiles sequentially to the last processor?
I want to split the fetching operations from MySQL DB into 4 parts in NiFi. I put 4 ExecuteSQLRecord sequentially and I want to have all the data in the last part(I am aware of MergeContent, But I want the success signal of all parts separately.). I have test it but only the flowfiles of last processor was available.
The scenario is like this:
ExecuteSQLRecord>ExecuteSQLRecord>ExecuteSQLRecord>ExecuteSQLRecord>PutFile
How Can I have all the flowfiles in the result?
Thanks

I recommend looking at FlowFile Concurrency configuration at process group level. It may provide the capability you are looking for.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvJx8vQnCNE
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Flowfile_Concurrency

I checked them but It does not work. I think this is not a complex scenario. Why does NiFi let me to connect two similar processors together? It has a logic behind it, right? Otherwise, It must show an error. If I want to make it clear, I want to abort PutFile operation when an error(For example, the second processor) happens. It is like commit/rollback operations in databases. Any Ideas?
